# Get phone numbers from incoming diverted call in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, telephony, telecommunication

I am new to Asterisk. I am not clear about my concept and don't know is it possible one.

Mobile number divert all incoming call to Virtual Telephone Number.  Virtual number divert to Asterisk PBX using SIP. If Asterisk receive a call, is it any possibility to get the phone number from and original destination number in Asterisk

Thanks

Comment: This is a systems administration question for a popular Open Source PBX system. I vote to move it to Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Check the sip headers and see if the itsp is passing it